# N-dimensional generalization of vector curl from elements of Jacobian

Tags: differential-geometry, multilinear-algebra

I want to determine whether a certain n-dimensional, simply-connected vector field is conservative. I can very easily calculate its Jacobian in numerical form.

In 3 dimensions, the problem is easy: the Jacobian is a 3x3 matrix, and the curl can be obtained from its elements:

[jacobian[2,1] - jacobian[1,2],  jacobian[0,2] - jacobian[2,0],  jacobian[1,0] - jacobian[0,1]]

A curl of zero would mean that the vector field is conservative.

But what if my Jacobian has 100 elements? The curl is only defined for 3 dimensions, but is there a formula for some high-dimensional generalization?

Comment: In 3 dimensions zero curl is not sufficient for a vector field to be conservative. It is also needed that the domain of the vector field is simply connected.

Comment: It's always simply-connected in my case.

Comment: OK, so see my response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a simply connected region of $\mathbb{R}^n$ the condition is that, in your notation, jacobian[i,j]=jacobian[j,i] for any i,j. This generalizes your curl condition.

Explanation: your vector field corresponds to a $1$-form $\omega$, and the vector field is conservative if and only if $\omega=d\phi$ for some $0$-form $\phi$. If the base is simply connected, then this is equivalent to $d\omega=0$. Now $d\omega$ is a $2$-form, and the local coordinates with respect to the standard basis are the differences jacobian[i,j]-jacobian[j,i] for distinct i,j.

Comment: Makes sense - so for n dimensions, we just need to test the Jacobian for symmetricity?

Comment: And what would happen if I decided to switch a exchange the order of a couple of coordinates in my basis? Wouldn't that stop the Jacobian being symmetric?

Comment: @Tarrare: No. Changing the order of coordinates corresponds to applying a permutation on the rows and the same permutation on the columns of the Jacobian. So symmetricity is preserved. In general, the exterior derivative $d\omega$ is a notion independent of the basis. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative

Comment: Fantastic, thanks- that makes total sense.